# Laravel Eloquent one-to-one relationship returning empty collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-relations

I am on a project where I am using custom PKs and FKs, and I'm trying to set up a one to one relationship.

For example, in Employee.php:

```
public function title()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Title', 'TitleID');
}
```

On Tinker, I  can retrieve an employee TitleID like so:

```
$employee = Employee::first();
$employee->TitleID;
```

Which returns:

> "6"

I have now made a model: Title.php:

```
class Title extends Model
{
    protected $table = "dbo.title";

    protected $primaryKey = 'TitleID';

}
```

I can retrieve the contents of this model correctly when running `$title = Title::all();` in Tinker.

I have set up a new relationship in Employee.php:

```
public function title()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Title', 'TitleID');
}
```

However, in Tinker (which I have restarted) when I run:

```
$employee = Employee::first();
$employee->title()->get();
```

It returns:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3027
>        all: [],
>      }

What have I done to set up this relationship incorrectly?

Comment: Is there any relative data? What is `Title::all()`?

Comment: You should also follow Laravel naming conventions, meaning that you use `title_id` on your Employee model instead of `TitleID`. Makes your life easier if you just follow the naming conventions.

Comment: @Qirel yes, there is relative data. You were right about it being to do with the naming conventions though! In this circumstance though, I am working with a legacy DB connected to several applications and have no control of the naming conventions for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that because the primary key of the other table isn't `id`, it wasn't able to find the collection.

However, according to the documentation, it reads:

> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the id (or the custom $primaryKey) column of the parent.

So I assumed that because I set a custom `$primaryKey` value, it would intuitively be able to find it - however it seems the issue was to do with the local key's name breaking Eloquent's convention.

I solved the issue by declaring both the foreign and local key respectively:

```
public function title()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Title', 'TitleID', 'TitleID');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the property `title` instead of calling `title()`:

```
$employee = Employee::first();
$employee->title;
```

Comment: That wasn't the issue, as you should still be able to access the title when using `()` which utilises the Query Builder. I've found the answer though, which I have posted below which you can check out :) Thanks for taking your time to have a look.